# My project uses '>=2.14.4 <3.0.0' of dart,but doing '>=2.11.9 <3.0.0' removes null safety.So does it select '2.11.9' from this range?

Tags: flutter, dart

> If yes,then from where does my VS code get it if I have dart sdk 2.14.4 installed on my device

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you are asking. What are your current settings and what is your problem with those settings?

Comment: Just asking how is it able to choose between SDK's backward versions if I have dart SDK 2.14.4 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those constraints are the *minimum* and *maximum* versions.

If you give a minimum version of 2.11.9, you cannot use null safety (came with 2.12.0), because it did not exist in 2.11.9. You promised your project would work with all versions from 2.11.9 to anything smaller than 3. And your compiler enforces that promise.

It doesn't matter what version you have installed.

Comment: So it always chooses the minimum one specified? Thank you for your answer...